# Instalar un driver de un TL-WN823N con make

Tags: linux, fedora

El problema es que al ejecutar el comando `sudo make` para compilar el archivo `Makefile` me sale esta leyenda en la terminal:

`/lib/modules/5.8.15-301.fc33.x86_64/build: no existe el fichero o el directorio.`

Es un problema porque con el gestor de archivos navegué hasta ese directorio y sí existe.

La distribución es Fedora 33.

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan posiblemente los kernel-headers. Para eso, debería servir el ejecutar

```
sudo yum update && sudo yum install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```